# How to remove duplicates from an array using forEach method in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array in that I have objects and strings now my goal is to filter all duplicates from strings and objects.

If you don't understand, please put a comment

```
const data = [
  'apple',
  'mango',
  'orange',
  'grapes',
  'apple',
  'mango',
  {
    name: 'Mark',
    age: 28
  },
  {
    name: 'Mark',
    age: 28
  },
  {
    name: 'James',
    age: 28
  },
  'sapota',
  'gaua',
  {
    name: 'Williams',
    age: 26
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    age: 24
  },
  'gaua'
]

console.log(data)
```

Comment: You haven't even described what a duplicate is. Are two elements with name 'John' duplicate of each other? Or do they have to have the same age too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method you could use assuming you have no circular data structures

```js
function removeDup(arr){
   let known = [];
   return arr.filter(elem => {
      let str = JSON.stringify(elem); // Get string of whatever item we are dealing with
      if(!known.includes(str)){  //Check to see if we have seen this item before
         known.push(str);  //If we havnt add it to seen list
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   });
}
```

Obviously this is constrained to anything that JSON.stringify can handle.
Also, this method assumes that in an array like:
`[{name: 'name'}, 'name']` 
the two names are different things and will both get returned. If you want to treat them the as duplicates let me know

Note this doesn't use a forEach loop but could VERY easily be change to use one.